# Updating HTML Element Every Second With Content From MySQL Database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'd like to have a div on my web page that is based off of the data in my MySQL database. When the data in the database changes, the content in the div should change as well.

Example: Let's say I have a field in the first row of a table called "server_statistics" in my MySQL database which keeps track of a server being online or offline. When the server goes offline, the MySQL field changes from 1 to 0. When it goes online, it goes from 0 to 1.

So I want to use Javascript to display the server status on my webpage and update it without refreshing the page.

I thought I'd be able to do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var int = self.setInterval("update()", 1000);
    function update() {
        var statusElement = document.getElementById("status");
        var status = "<?php 
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server_statistics LIMIT 1"));
            mysql_close($con);
            echo $row[0]; ?>";
        if (status == 0) {
            statusElement.style.color = "red";
            statusElement.innerHTML = "offline";
        }
        else {
            statusElement.style.color = "green";
            statusElement.innerHTML = "online";
        }
    }
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. The page needs to be refreshed for it to update and I don't know why...

I've read I can use JQuery but I have no knowledge of this language at all.

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var int = self.setInterval("update()", 1000);
    function update() {
        $('#status').load('load.php');
    }
</script>
```

and then in load.php I had this:

```
<?php
    echo "test";
?>
```

But nothing happened after 1 second passed. I'm probably doing it wrong because as I said, I don't know anything about this JQuery/AJAX stuff.

So how can I accomplish retrieving a field from a MySQL database at every specified interval and then automatically update an HTML element accordingly? It would be ideal to only update the HTML when a change occurred in the database but for now, I just want it to change every few seconds or minutes...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it update correctly when you refresh?

Comment: Where is `self` defined (as used by this code: `var int = self.setInterval("update()", 1000);`)? Change it to `window.setInterval` or just `setInterval` and it should work.

Comment: When you do the first method it is just hardcoding the status in the javascript on page load, thats why when you refresh it works. You need to use ajax to query a page that echos out the status.

Comment: No, the timer isn't the problem. The update() method is getting called every second but the value just isn't changing for some reason. I want to use AJAX but have no idea why loading anything from a php file into an HTML element won' work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do is utilize AJAX. Your page will need to make a request to the server each time it wants to check the status. There are two ways to do it: manually refresh the page yourself, or use an AJAX call.

AJAX really isn't all that difficult, you start by creating a separate PHP page `check_status.php` with the following in it:

```
<?php 
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server_statistics LIMIT 1"));
    mysql_close($con);
    echo $row[0]; ?>
```

Then, in your HTML page, the easiest way to do this would be to use jQuery:

```
var statusIntervalId = window.setInterval(update, 1000);

function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check_status.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            if (parseInt(data) == 0) {
                $("#status").css({ color: "red" }).text("offline");
            } else {
                $("#status").css({ color: "green" }).text("online");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's it really. Every second, it will call the `update()` method which makes an AJAX call and inserts the result back into your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I can't get it to work at all :S The div where I want the data to be put just isn't updating... I have a div like <div id="status"></div> and the update function IS getting called every second. My check_status.php is in the same directory as the page containing the javascript function. I've tried just echoing a string instead of a MySQL query but nothing happens... I don't know why it's not working...

Comment: I updated my code a little bit to make it slightly more robust. See if that helps. If not, maybe we can help you debug a little more, which browser are you using?

Comment: what string were you echoing?

Comment: When you manually call check_status.php in your browser, what does it display for you?

Comment: Sorry guys, I feel dumb lol. I didn't know anything about AJAX and didn't know that you had to import it by doing <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">... I thought it didn't need that like Javascript doesn't. I got it working now though and it works great, thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1226792 - That thought crossed my mind, but I figured you'd be able to figure that out. Glad it's working out for you now!

Answer (score 1):

instead of `var int = self.setInterval("update()", 1000);` try using `self.setInterval(update, 1000);` and place it after the update function.

Comment: Still doesn't work :S The function is getting called every second but the "status" variable doesn't change even after changing it in the database... it's weird. I have to refresh the page and then it'll change.